# Logstash: How to aggregate over some eventType

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have few events of different types like: 'Login' 'Logout' 'Selected' etc for each individual playerId. How can i aggregate data for each eventType.

One way is to create Maps for each type and store data (increment) but is there any generic way so that in future if i add another Event type in my log file as 'XYZ' the logstash code should work and aggregate events and send to elasticSearch.

Comment: What have you tried?  What does your input look like?  What's your expected output?

Comment: There usually isn't a lot of aggregation in logstash, but rather in elasticsearch (kibana).